# Apache Ivy: Difference between local Ivy cache and local repository

Tags: java, apache, ant, ivy

By default Ivy installs a "local cache" under your `<HOME>/.ivy2` directory. But if I decide to "host" a local repository on the same machine, say, at `<HOME>/workbench/ivy/`, then how are these two concepts different? Isn't a cache the same thing as an artifact repository?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The concepts page describes the function of the ivy cache and the kinds of file it contains:

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html

In a nutshell, the ivy cache is designed to improve performance, it's not meant to be the definitive copy of the files a build depends on. One never publishes to the cache. This is what an ivy repository is used for.

Additonal notes:

- There is an ivy [cleancache](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cleancache.html) task designed to purge ivy's cache (Something which is recommended, periodically, to cater for misbehaving repositories)
- In Maven-land the "local" repository is also used as a cache..... ivy has a cleaner separation of purpose.

Comment: Ahhh, you nailed it when you wrote "One never publishes to the cache", that was a tangential question I had as well.  Thank you!

Comment: There is a `local` subdirectory in my Ivy cache directory. I think this is related to the "Apache Ivy Local Repository". Is not this a kind of "publish to cache"?

Comment: @clapas The "local" and "shared" directories are the default repository locations as documented here: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/defaultconf.html.