# Using a copy of the .ivy2 cache as SBT resolver source

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I'm trying to package a few in-house artifacts for use with SBT. I would just use the `libs` directory in most cases, but there are multiple projects that share the same artifacts.

I've been trying to use the directory structure that is produced by SBT as a basis for this small repository. It stores the artifacts in `.ivy2` like so:

```
.ivy2/cache/[org-with-dots]/[module]/[artifact]-[version].[ext]
```

I've copied the stuff i need under `cache` to it's own folder and then tried the following patterns in SBT to no avail:

```
resolvers += "cache" at "file:/../ivy-cache"
resolvers += Resolver.file("cache", file("../ivy-cache"))
resolvers += Resolver.file("cache", file("../ivy-cache"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
resolvers += Resolver.file("cache", file("../ivy-cache"))(Patterns("[organization]/[module]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"))
```

None of these work. The closest was the last one, but organization comes out with slashes instead of dots. The `Resolver.ivyStylePatterns` used dots in the organization, but expected a folder called `ivys` to be used.

So I have a two part question:

1. Should I just be doing something else to capture these locally hosted artifacts? Im not building them, so `publish` is not desirable.
2. Is there a way to specify the pattern I want above without doing a string replacement from `/` to `.` in the organization component?

Comment: If the jars are in the cache, why do you think sbt would go as far as to downloading them once more? They're already cached, aren't they? It's a local cache of the deps you've once requested to pull down.

Comment: I'm giving the code to someone who isn't on our intranet, which has it's own artifactory server. So I'm replacing our internal artifact servers with a cached repository for those jars.

Comment: It'd be likely easier to just upload the jars to a proper repository manager and let others use it...*properly*.

Comment: Obviously that is not an option, else I wouldn't be doing this song and dance. That being said, the tool supports filesystem-borne repositories so my usage is, in fact, proper. It's even in the manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer, `Pattern` has an apply overload which takes a boolean parameter for its first argument. When `true` it uses a Maven style organization string which uses slashes to separate the components, when `false` it uses Ivy style (dots).

Here's what worked (with SBT 0.3.9):

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("cache", file("../ivy-cache"))(Patterns(false,"[organization]/[module]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"))
```

PS: if someone provides a better workflow instead, i will accept that over this answer...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the ivy cache has a different file system layout, which might explain the problems you're having with pattern matching in [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html)

Secondly (and more importantly) the ivy cache is not designed to be used as the definitive copy of files a build depends on. For example a cache might be purged (indeed ivy contains a [command](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cleancache.html) that does exactly that).

Related to the following questions:

- [Apache Ivy: Difference between local Ivy cache and local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366281/apache-ivy-difference-between-local-ivy-cache-and-local-repository)
- [Unable to add jar file to .ivy cache manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314433/unable-to-add-jar-file-to-ivy-cache-manually)

Comment: 1, yes and I'm trying to match that layout but don't see any direct way to do so, which I find strange. And 2, that's why i copied the resources to another directory that isn't affected by cache functions, like purging.