# Setting up a local repository for a Scala project in a closed network

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, resolver

I'd like to use scala project in a closed networks. For this, I've tried to setup my local repository using ivy cache(`~/.ivy2/cache`) as follow steps.

---

##### 1. Collecting artifacts from the Ivy cache:

- Set `useCouriser := false` and built all of my projects.
- Copied `~/.ivy2/cache/` to my local repository at `/opt/sbt-repo/ivy` using the rsync command (`rsync -av ~/.ivy2/cache/ /opt/sbt-repo/ivy/`).

---

##### 2. Setting up the `~/.sbt/repositories` file:

- Updated the repositories file with the following content:

  ```
  [repositories]
    local
    ivy-repo1: file:///opt/sbt/ivy/
    ivy-repo2: file:///opt/sbt/ivy/, [organization]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
  ```
- I assumed that `[organization]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]` represents the pattern in `~/.ivy2/cache`.
- For example, the artifact `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.17/scala-library-2.12.17.jar` is stored in `~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.17.jar`.

---

However, SBT is unable to find any artifacts. I've referred to the following references, but couldn't find a suitable solution:

- [Using a copy of the .ivy2 cache as SBT resolver source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619873/using-a-copy-of-the-ivy2-cache-as-sbt-resolver-source)
- [SBT resolver](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html)

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't do any of that: in open environment, run SBT commands to build your project, in closed environment copy the `.ivy2` folder from open environment. There might be other folders to copy though. Also why not coursier?

Comment: Sbt use .ivy directory by default, no need to specify it's directly (I don't understand why you changed .sbt/repositories file, I never did it). But you can add some resolvers, including to dir, internal or external host. https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html